# How to pass current record context in a Utility Bar Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, spring17, utility-bar

I'm trying to access current record id in a `Lightning Component` when put into `Utility Bar`. But it comes out to be empty all the time. I've implemented `force:hasRecordId` interface in my component but `recordId` attribute remain empty when I launch the component in `Utility Bar`.

Is there a way we can achieve this function of reading current record id in utility bar?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I'd love to be able to get some context in my component!

Comment: Nopes, nothing yet.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this may have been resolved in the Winter '18 release. I just added a component to the utility bar that implements `force:hasRecordId` and it does pull it in.

For reference, here is the relevant component attributes:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
```

And here is the JS controller that fires on init:

```
handleRecordChange: function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
    // only call server if user is on step 1
    var step = cmp.get("v.step");
    if (step == 1) {
        var recId = cmp.get("v.recordId"); 
        if (recId != null) {
            // delegate to helper
            hlp.getRecordInfo(cmp, cmp.get("v.recordId")); 
        } else {
            cmp.set("v.recordContext", false); 
            cmp.set("v.step",0); 
        }
    }
}
```

I think for this to work your Lightning Component needs to be on **API version 41.0**. You can adjust this by clicking the "Bundle Version Settings" button in the cloud dev console.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @kev4ev, do you have an example you can share? Just tried in a Winter '18 org and it appears it's still not working.

Comment: @GusMelendez Just updated my answer with some sample code. Note the last part regarding setting your component API version to 41.0

Answer (score 0):

this works for me to get recordId for a component  in the Utility Bar:

<aura:component description="Aura Container in Utility Bar for LWC cmp"
implements="force:hasRecordId, force:lightningQuickAction, lightning:utilityItem"  access="global">

```
<c:childLwcCmp recordId="{!v.recordId}"  />
```

</aura:component>

export default class childLwcCmp extends LightningElement {

```
_recordId;

@api
get recordId() {
    return this._recordId;
}
set recordId(value) {
    this.setAttribute('recordId', value);
    this._recordId = value;
```

//for the first time NULL comes, but then immediately the current recordID comes from the aura

```
    if (this.recordId == null) {   
        console.log('-/-NULL-/-', this.recordId);
    } else {
        this.doInit();
    }
}
```