# How do you pass a record id into a flow variable using utility bar in LEX?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, utility-bar

I created a flow with a text input only variable that inserts the current account record ID because later in the process it updates fields on that account record.

I know how to insert the value of this variable using a button with the following

```
/flow/Flow_Name?AccountID={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}
```

Now, instead of using a button, I want to launch this flow using Utility Bar in LEX. I do this by editing Sales Console under Lightning Experience App Manager and under the Utility Bar under Component Properties, there is the option to enter values for flow variables. This is where I can enter the variable I created in the flow (AccountID).

My question is- what do I enter so the Account ID that launches the flow is used?

I’ve tried using:

- `{!Record.Id}`
- `{!Account.Id}`
- `?AccountID={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}`

Does anyone know if it is possible to pass the record ID into the flow when launching a from the Utility Bar and how?

Side note: I know it is possible to pass the Record ID into the flow using a Lightning Component in Lightning Pages. There is a checkbox titled Pass record ID into this variable. So, it looks like it is possible to pass a record ID, but I want to do it from the Utility Bar and not from a Lightning Component in Lightning Pages.

Comment: did you try this? [Embed a Flow in a Lightning Page] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_lab.htm

Comment: Yes, I have tried the above and it does work but I was hoping to accomplish the same task in the utility bar.

Answer (score 1):

This seems currently not possible. Please also see [this Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156396/how-to-pass-current-record-context-in-a-utility-bar-lightning-component)

`{!v.recordId}` is not present in a Utility Bar Component even if you implement the [`force:hasRecordId` interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hasrecordid.htm?search_text=hasRecordId)

Comment: Yea, it doesn't seem like it works. Thanks for looking into it.